# How can I connect to my replicaset via DNS and private IP?

Tags: replication, mongodb, dns

I have 2 node setup

```
10.1.0.7  - mongodb-1.com (primary)
10.1.0.8  - mongodb-2.com (secondary)
```

here is my mongod.conf

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0
  tls:
    mode: allowTLS
    certificateKeyFile: /etc/mongodb/certificates/mongodb.pem
security:
  authorization: enabled
  keyFile: /home/dbuser/repset
replication:
  replSetName: "repset"
```

here is my rs.conf()

```
{
  _id: 'repset',
  version: 4,
  term: 3,
  members: [
    {
      _id: 0,
      host: '10.1.0.7:27017',
      arbiterOnly: false,
      buildIndexes: true,
      hidden: false,
      priority: 1,
      tags: {},
      secondaryDelaySecs: Long("0"),
      votes: 1
    },
    {
      _id: 1,
      host: '10.1.0.8:27017',
      arbiterOnly: false,
      buildIndexes: true,
      hidden: false,
      priority: 1,
      tags: {},
      secondaryDelaySecs: Long("0"),
      votes: 1
    }
  ],
  protocolVersion: Long("1"),
  writeConcernMajorityJournalDefault: true,
  settings: {
    chainingAllowed: true,
    heartbeatIntervalMillis: 2000,
    heartbeatTimeoutSecs: 10,
    electionTimeoutMillis: 10000,
    catchUpTimeoutMillis: -1,
    catchUpTakeoverDelayMillis: 30000,
    getLastErrorModes: {},
    getLastErrorDefaults: { w: 1, wtimeout: 0 },
    replicaSetId: ObjectId("641aebeb4623f6fd0e700cf2")
  }
}
```

Now my proposed setup would be there are 2 application servers that will connect to this replica set. 1 is via private IP and the other is via DNS name. Now when I connect via private IP. it is working fine. I cant do the same when connecting via DNS name. is that possible?

I am connecting to this via this script below (via Private IP that's working)

```
mongodb://username:password@10.1.0.7:27017,10.1.0.8:27017/?authSource=admin&replicaSet=repset
```

The script below is the one that could not connect (via DNS)

```
mongodb://username:password@mongodb-1.com:27017,mongodb-2.com:27017/?authSource=admin&replicaSet=repset
```

UPDATE: I do not know why this works but when I try to add each domain name as replicaset members.

```
rs.add('mongodb-1.com:27017')
rs.add('mongodb-2.com:27017')
```

I am now able to connect publicly via this command

```
mongodb://username:password@mongodb-1.com:27017,mongodb-2.com:27017/?authSource=admin&replicaSet=repset
```

Comment: You should initiate the replica set with hostname instead of IP-Address, that's also [recommended by MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/#hostnames). Then it should work in either ways. Note, the certificate may also fail if you put IP-Address in the Subject Alternative Name (SAN), see https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/160787/ip-address-in-subjectaltname So using the hostname should be always the better one.

Comment: Hi. well my use-case is that when my application server will connect to it (via private IP since they have same vnet) cert is not required so tls may be disabled. When I set the replica set to hostnames (mongodb-1.com or mongodb-2.com) my application server could not connect to it

Comment: My architecture would be 2 mongodb servers (azure) 2 app server (1 azure, 1 from onprem) now the onprem app server would connect to DB via DNS with TLS enabled (hopefully) then the azure app would connect via private IP.